# Python - Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT) - turtle module

Tags: python, sigabrt

I have an issue with my code ; I use the turtle module inside this function in PyCharm :

```
def squares_around_taxi(longitude, latitude, azimuth_taxi, size=square_size):

    crocodile = turtle.Turtle()
    crocodile.home()

    long = longitude
    lat = latitude

    crocodile.forward(long)
    crocodile.degrees(360)
    crocodile.left(90)
    crocodile.forward(lat)

    alpha = azimuth_taxi
    x = []
    y = []
    size_square = size

    crocodile.left(alpha)
    crocodile.forward(size_square / 2)
    position = crocodile.position()
    x.append(position[0])
    y.append(position[1])
    crocodile.left(90)
    crocodile.forward(size_square)
    position = crocodile.position()
    x.append(position[0])
    y.append(position[1])
    crocodile.left(90)
    crocodile.forward(size_square)
    position = crocodile.position()
    x.append(position[0])
    y.append(position[1])
    crocodile.left(90)
    crocodile.forward(size_square)
    position = crocodile.position()
    x.append(position[0])
    y.append(position[1])
    crocodile.forward(size_square)
    position = crocodile.position()
    x.append(position[0])
    y.append(position[1])
    crocodile.left(90)
    crocodile.forward(size_square)
    position = crocodile.position()
    x.append(position[0])
    y.append(position[1])

    coordinates = []
    for i in range(len(x)):
        coordinates.append((x[i],y[i]))

    left_square = Polygon([coordinates[0], coordinates[1], coordinates[2], coordinates[3]])
    right_square = Polygon([coordinates[0], coordinates[3], coordinates[4], coordinates[5]])

    return left_square, right_square
```

It returns this error message, that I don't understand : Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT) 
I tried using the debugger mode, which shows that the code does not work from the first line : crocodile = turtle.Turtle().

I use the turtle module in another script where it works just fine...
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

SIGABRT is a low level C system call to abort a process when a critical error occurs.

In your case it's because you are assigning a default string value without quotes.

It should be

```py
def squares_around_taxi(longitude, latitude, azimuth_taxi , size='square_size'):
```

not

```py
def squares_around_taxi(longitude, latitude, azimuth_taxi , size=square_size):
```

Comment: I tried to change that, but it did not work. Even after suppressing the parameter "size", it still does not work...

Comment: @KungFuPanda try to run the function on it's own and see if it runs. It did for me